# WordPress custom form action url

Tags: comments, forms, actions

Is there any way to replace standard WordPress comments form action, which usually looks like this:

`<form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">`

to something custom WITHOUT altering comments.php (i.e. for a plugin, so you don't have to make end-users edit their themes):

`<form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" some_java_script some_tag="some_value" method="post" id="commentform">`

Comment: I don't need to replace action URL, I need to add some stuff in `<form>` tag, just like it's shown in the original post (see last 2 lines).

Answer (score 2):

simple with jQuery:

```
//first make sure you have jQuery on that page
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','make_sure_i_have_jquery');
function make_sure_i_have_jquery(){
    if (!is_admin())
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
//then just change the url to you own
    add_action('wp_footer','change_comment_form');
    function make_sure_i_have_jquery(){
        if (!is_admin() && (is_page() || is_single()))
            echo '<script> $("#commentform").attr("action", "http://yourUrl.com"); </script>';
    }
```

just paste this in your theme's functions.php or the plugin your are develop and change `http://yourUrl.com` to the url you want

Answer (score 0):

paste this in your theme's functions.php:

```
add_action( 'comment_form_before', 'my_comment_form_before' );
function my_comment_form_before() {
    ob_start();
}
add_action( 'comment_form_after', 'my_comment_form_after' );
function my_comment_form_after() {
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $html = preg_replace(
        '/wp-comments-post.php"/',
        'wp-comments-post.php" some_java_script some_tag="some_value"',
        $html
    );
    echo $html;
}
```